# Referencing List Positions of Words

Tags: python

I have a list of words which I have created through an Input statement:
phrase = input(Please enter a phrase:) My Name Is My Name Is

```
phrase.split()
Phrase = ["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Name", "Is"]
```

I have then created a UsedWords list (see below) by enumerating through the Phrase list and appending all the Words that were used to create the original phrase.

```
WordsUsed =  ["My","Name","Is"]
indexOfWords=[0      1     2 ]
```

I then stored the index of each letter (within the WordsUsed list) into a new list called indexOfWords by using the built-in in method.

So, what I want to do now is re-create the original phrase within the phrase list, but replace it by the index of the Word in the WordsUsed list. So for example:

```
Phrase = ["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Name", "Is"]
WordsUsed =  ["My","Name","Is"]
NewPhrase = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

I have tried as suggested by Kasra the following:

```
d={j:i for i,j in enumerate(set(Phrase))}
[d[i] for i in Phrase]
```

However this returns the following output for the phrase: 
Phrase = ["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Name", "Is"] output [2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]
I belive that it is outputting the list lexicographicaly. The Actual output should be [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

Does anybody have any ideas on how to overcome this.

Cheers

Comment: Store the index and count of each word from the phrase into a dictionary

    d={i:phrase.count(phrase[i]) for i in xrange(len(phrase))}

Comment: You must add and example with `["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Is", "Name"]` for refusing of using `list.index` like the OhAuth's answer!

Comment: Kasra sorry I didn't understand your comment...

Comment: @PythonNewBee  I mean that  OhAuth's answer gives a correct result for your example be cause the order of duplicate words in your list at first part and second part is same its `"My", "Name", "Is"`, till it gives `[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1]` for `["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Is", "Name"]`

Comment: ["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Name", "Is"] is just an example, I would also expect it to work for ["My", "Name", "Is", "Is", "Name", "Is"], however I have found that this does not and produces an incorrect output

Comment: @PythonNewBee check my answer, it should produce what you want

Comment: therealprashant what is xrange? sorry I am new to all of this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[WordsUsed.index(word) for word in Phrase]
```

---

## What it gives you

Given `["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Name", "Is"]` you'll get `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]`.

Given `["My", "Name", "My", "My", "Name"]` you'll get `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`.

Hopefully this is more readable and compact answer.

Comment: This doesn't produce expected out put for `["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Is", "Name"] `

Comment: Brilliant this has worked a treat! Do I just click the up arrow to vote!

Comment: @PythonNewBee Except the answer as well by clicking the green tick if the answer solved your problem. It will be useful to other users who may come across this question.

Comment: Yep already done that, just one more additional question OhAuth. if I wanted the index to start at 1 as opposed to zero, would this be possible? Given ["My", "Name", "Is", "My", "Name", "Is"] I get [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]. etc

Comment: Managed to do it by iterating through the list and setting the item t +1. might be a long winded way, so would welcome other methods. Cheers

Comment: @PythonNewBee a more elegant way would be `[WordsUsed.index(word)  + 1 for word in Phrase]`